# Wait for closure completion to make a synchronous function return

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch

I have a function that returns a Bool. This Bool value is set inside a closure that is executed after get network response(network request is performed in a background thread).

The problem is that I need to wait for closure completion ir order to obtain the value that I need to return.

In order to achieve this I have used DispatchGroup but it does not work. As result my application is get blocked by some kind of deadlock.

```
private func isOriginal() -> Bool {
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        var isOriginal = true
        group.enter()
        let parameters = GetIsOriginalParameters(completion: { result in
            defer {
                group.leave()
            }
            guard case .success(let isOriginalResult) = result else {
                return
            }
            isOriginal = isOriginalResult
        })
        getIsOriginalUseCase.run(parameters) //calls network request 
        group.wait()
        return isOriginal
    }
```

Notice that I have test with `DispatchSemaphore` obtaining same behaviour.
**I can't support Async/Await**

Edit:
This code is part of an enum initiated from AppDelegate after open a push notification:

```
public var navigationInfo: NavInfo {
        switch self {
        .
        .
        case .createNew:
            return handleTypeNavigation()
        .
        .
        }
    }

    private func handleTypeNavigation() -> NavInfo {
        if isOriginal() {
            return Navigation.original
        } else {
            return Navigation.notOriginal
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is a mistake to try and turn an asynchronous method into a synchronous one.  As you are blocking the main thread, you will at the very least impact app responsiveness and in all likelihood create a deadlock. The appropriate solution is for `isOriginal` to also accept a completion handler and invoke it from the `GetIsOriginalParameters` completion handler

Comment: You are basically trying to implement async/await without using async/await - not going to happen. Use completion block instead, like said above.

Comment: There are some kludgy workarounds to this problem, but the right solution is to embrace the asynchronous patterns, such as completion handler closure. Show us what the caller of this function is doing and we can probably help you out. The problem with waiting on the main thread is not only your current deadlock problem, but if you get past that, you'll still have temporarily frozen UI, risk watchdog process killing your app, tying up worker threads, etc.

Comment: @Rob I have added the code which is invoking the function in question. As I said, this code is called after open a push notification ir order to know how to nagivate

Comment: You can't use an asynchronous function in a computed variable. You need to refactor to eliminate the computed variable and call the asynchronous operation with a completion handler and do  your work in the completion handler